# Solve $\cos^{n}x-\sin^{n}x=1$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve $\cos^{n}x-\sin^{n}x=1$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$

I have no idea how to deal with this crazy question. One idea came into my mine is factorization, but I can't go on... Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: First, carefully, do $n=1$ and $n=2.$

Comment: $\cos^nx-1=\sin^nx$
$=>(\cos x-1)(...)=sinx(sin^{n-1}x)$, 
$=>-2sin^2\frac{x}{2}(\cos x-1)(...)=2sin\frac{x}{2}cos\frac{x}{2}(sin^{n-1}x)$, Clearly, $sin\frac{x}{2}=0$ is a solution =>$x=2m\pi$ where m is any integer.

Comment: RE lab bhattacharjee: How do you get $-2sin^{2}{x/2}$?

Comment: @jasoncube, $cos2A=1-2sin^2A$

Comment: RE lab bhattacharjee: So you have typed the extra $cosx-1$ right?

Comment: As I've taken it as factor of $cos^nx-1$ as (a-b) is always a factor of $(a^n-b^n)$

Comment: But the $\cos x-1$ should have been changed to $-2\sin^{2}\frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: Is the '-' sign discernible?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @http://www.cut-the-knot.org/wiki-math/index.php?n=MathematicalOlympiads.IMO1961Problem3

Comment: This problem is IMO $1961$ Problem $3$. [Here's an AoPS thread about it.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h55221p343304)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874442/solve-cosn-x-sinn-x-1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874477/solve-cosn-x-sinnx-1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023673/general-solution-of-the-equation-sin2015-phi-cos2015-phi-1

Comment: https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-solution-for-cos-nx-sin-nx-1-witn-n-in-nn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is even, then

$$1= \cos^{n}x-\sin^{n}x \leq 1-0=1$$

with equality if and only if $\cos^{n}x=1, \sin^n(x)=0$.

If $n$ is odd,

$$1= \cos^{n}x-\sin^{n}x \,,$$

implies $\cos(x) \geq 0$ and $\sin(x) <0$. Let $\cos(x)=y, \sin(x)=-z$, with $y,z \geq 0$.

$$y^n+z^n=1$$
$$y^2+z^2=1$$

Case 1: $n=1$:

Then , since $0 \leq y,z \leq 1$ we have

$$1 =y+z \geq y^2+z^2 =1$$

with equality if and only if $y=y^2, z=z^2$.

Case 2: $n \geq 3$:

Then , since $0 \leq y,z \leq 1$ we have

$$1 =y^2+z^2 \geq y^n+z^n =1$$

with equality if and only if $y^2=y^n, z^2=z^n$.

Comment: Sorry for this late comment, but I was checking this question today, why  in case 1  you have  $ y+z \leq y^2 +z^2$ ? Knowing that $y,z \leq 1$ ??

Comment: @Nizar You are right, the inequalities are backwards.

Answer (score 4):

We consider the $2\pi$-periodic function
$$f(x):=\cos^n x-\sin^n x$$
and determine its stationary points in $[0,2\pi[\ $. One gets
$$f'(x)=-n\cos x\sin x\bigl(\cos^{n-2}x+\sin^{n-2}x\bigr)\ ;$$
therefore the stationary points  are the multiples of ${\pi\over2}$, and for odd $n>2$ the points where $\cos x=-\sin x$, i.e., the points ${3\pi\over4}$ and ${7\pi\over4}$. In these points one has the values
$$f(0)=1, \quad f({\pi\over2})=-1,\quad f(\pi)=(-1)^n,\quad f({3\pi\over2})=(-1)^{n-1}\ ,$$
furthermore for  $n=2m+1$ the values
$$f({3\pi\over4})=-{\sqrt{2}\over 2^m}, \quad f({7\pi\over4})={\sqrt{2}\over 2^m}<1\ .$$
It follows that the global maximal value of $f$ is $1$. This value is taken at $0$ and $\pi$ if $n$ is even, and at $0$ and ${3\pi\over2}$ if $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

For all $n$, when $\cos(x)=1$, $\sin(x)=0$.

For even $n$, when $\cos(x)=-1$, $\sin(x)=0$.

For odd $n$, when $\sin(x)=-1$, $\cos(x)=0$.

Comment: I guess that, it is implicitly used in robjohn's solution that $x^{n/2} + (1 - x)^{n/2} < 1$ whenever $0 < x < 1$ and $n > 2$. Thus for $n \geq 3$, $$|\cos^n x - \sin^n x| \leq |\cos^n x| + |\sin^n x| < 1$$ unless either $\cos x = 0$ or $\sin x = 0$.