# Solve $\cos^n x + \sin^n x =1 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

the solutions of this equation as a function of the value of $n$??

\begin{align}      
 \cos^n x + \sin^n x =1 
\end{align}

I already found the solution if n is odd,

Comment: What is your solution for odd $n$? If your logic is similar to how I'd solve that, it'd be easy to get to even $n$.

Comment: it is only develop the calculations, I find that zero is the solution if n is odd but the other cases is difficult and calculating sally does not give a result

Comment: Interesting things might happen with $n$ negative. But for $n\gt 2$, note that $|\sin^n x|\le |\sin^2 x|$, with equality hardly ever.

Comment: let $n > 2$. we know that $|\cos x|^2+|\sin x|^2 = 1$. if $0 < |\cos x| < 1$ and $0 < |\sin x| < 1$ then  $|\cos x|^n < |\cos x|^2$ and $|\sin x|^k < |\sin x|^2$ so $|\cos x|^n + |\sin x|^n < 1$, hence $|\cos x| = 1, \sin x  = 0$ or $|\sin x| = 1, \cos x  = 0$. (the same argument applies when $n < 2$ in the reverse way)

Comment: @infox09: I believe that a similar question was already asked on this site, althought I wasn't able to find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, we can write it as $n = 2k+1, k \ge 1$.
$$1 = |\sin^{2k+1}x + \cos^{2k+1}x| \le |\sin x|\cdot \sin^{2k}x + |\cos x|\cdot \cos^{2k}x \le \sin^{2k}x+\cos^{2k}x \le \sin^2 x + \cos^2x = 1.$$ Thus, $|\sin x| = 1, 0$, and you can find $x$ from this.

If $n = 1$, then $$\sin x + \cos x = 1\implies (\sin x+\cos x)^2 = 1 \implies \sin (2x) = 0 \implies 2x = m\pi \implies x = \dfrac{m\pi}{2}, m \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

If $n$ is even, then $$n \ge 2 \implies 1 = \sin^2x + \cos^2 x \ge \sin^n x+\cos^n x = 1\implies \cos^2 x = 1, 0 \implies \cos x = 0, \pm 1 \implies x = m\pi, \pm\dfrac{\pi}{2} + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: How have you concluded $\sin^{2k}x + \cos^{2k}x\le \sin^2 x$ for $k\ge 1$? Its not.

Comment: There is  a $\cdots + \cos^2 x $ that you missed.....

Answer (score 8):

Hint:

For positive $n$: You know that for any $x$, $$\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1,$$ and both the terms on the left are positive. For $n = 2k$, if $x$ is a solution, then you have $\cos^{2k} x + \sin^{2k} x = 1$, so $$(\cos^2 x)^k + (\sin^2 x)^k = 1$$.

Look at those two displayed equations and ask yourself, "How are $\cos^2 x $ and $(\cos^2 x)^k$ related? Which is larger in general?"

For negative $n$: A similar argument should work, but with the inequality reversed.

Comment: my real question is  about  cos(x)^n-sin(x)^n=1

Comment: OK. Well, I answered the question you asked, and I'm not going down the rathole of a chameleon question. Best of luck addressing the other. You'll get best results if you actually answer the questions posed in the comments (e.g., if you carefully explain how you addressed the odd-$n$ case).

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice geometrical interpretation if you will.

We know $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$ for all $x$. You want to solve $\cos^n x + \sin^n x = 1$. If $a = \cos x$ and $b = \sin x$, then you want to solve the simultaneous equations:
$$
a^2 + b^2 = 1,\quad\quad\mbox{circunference}\\
a^n + b^n = 1,\quad\mbox{super-circunference}
$$

The circunference and [super-circunference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) for $n > 2$ will intercept only in the points $(1, 0)$, $(0, 1)$, $(-1, 0)$, $(0, -1)$. The greater than $n$, the more the super-circunference will look like a square.

Comment: Perhaps note explicitly that your solution requires $n$ to be even. (Otherwise the absolute values in the definition of "super-ellipse" can't be omitted.)

Answer (score 0):

If $\cos x\sin x\not=0$, then $|\cos x|=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$ and  $|\sin x|=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ are both strictly less than $1$, which implies $\cos^nx+\sin^nx\lt\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ for $n\gt2$.  For $n=1$, $\cos x+\sin x=1$ implies $\cos^2x+2\cos x\sin x+\sin^2x=1$, which implies $\cos x\sin x=0$.  In sum, when $n$ is a positive integer other than $2$, $\cos^nx+\sin^nx=1$ implies $x$ is a multiple of $\pi/2$.  If $n$ is even, *any* (integer) multiple of $\pi/2$ is a solution.  If $n$ is odd, the multiple must be congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod $4$.

For negative integers $n$, we cannot have $\cos x\sin x=0$.  If $n\lt0$ is even, then $\cos x\sin x\not=0$ implies $\cos^n+\sin^n\gt\cos^2+\sin^2=1$, so the equation has no solutions.  If $n\lt0$ is odd, however, there are solutions.  In particular, there is always a solution with $-\pi/2\lt x\lt 0$, since $\sec x\to\infty$ as $x\to-\pi/2^+$ while $\csc x\to-\infty$ as $x\to0^-$.

Finally, if $n=0$, the equation presumably has no solutions, since $\cos^0x+\sin^0x=1+1=2\not=1$ if $\cos x\sin x\not=0$ and isn't clearly defined if $\cos x\sin x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$ it can be solved by squaring both sides and OP also solved. For $n=2$ the equation is true for all $x$. So assume that $n\geq 3$.

Let $f(x)=\cos^n x+\sin^n x$. Then $f'(x)=n\sin x\cos x(\sin^{n-2}x-\cos^{n-2} x)$. For extrema, $f'(x)=0$ gives $\cos x=0$, $\sin x=0$, $\tan x=1$ or $\tan x=-1$ for $n$ even. But for $\tan x=\pm1$, the value of $f(x)$ can be at most $(\frac{1}{\sqrt2})^n+(\frac{1}{\sqrt2})^n=2^{1-\frac n2}<1$ since $1-\frac n2<0$ due to the assumption. And we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let’s assume that both $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are non-zero, then $$
\cos ^n x<\cos ^2 x \textrm{  and } \sin ^n x<\sin ^2 x.
$$
Adding them together, we get
$$
\sin ^n x+\cos ^n x<\sin ^2 x+\cos ^2 x=1 \Rightarrow \sin ^n x+\cos ^n x=1 \textrm{ has no solution.}
$$
Therefore $\cos x=0$ or $\sin x=0.$
Now we need to consider the parity of $n.$

A. When $n$ is even,

(i) $\cos x=0 \wedge \sin x= \pm 1 \Rightarrow x=n \pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$

(ii) $\sin x=0 \wedge \cos x= \pm 1 \Rightarrow x=n \pi$ and therefore

$$\boxed{x=n \pi+\frac{\pi}{2} \textrm{  or }n \pi \textrm{  for any }n \in \mathbb{Z}.}$$

B. When $n$ is odd,

(i) $\cos x=0 \wedge \sin x=1 \Rightarrow x=2 n \pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$

(ii) $\sin x=0 \wedge \cos x=1 \Rightarrow x=2n \pi$ and therefore

$$\boxed{x=2 n \pi+\frac{\pi}{2} \textrm{  or }2 n \pi \textrm{  for any }n \in \mathbb{Z}.}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\cos^n x + \sin^n x =1 $ has solution if and only if both terms are not negative, therefore we need to consider just two cases with $n$ even

- $0<|\cos x|<1$ and $n>2$

$$\cos^n x + \sin^n x < \cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$$

- $|\cos x|=0\;\lor\; |\cos x|=1$

$$\cos^n x + \sin^n x =1+0=1$$