# Solve $\cos^n x -\sin^n x =1$ for $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I already post a question on the solution of $$\cos^n x +\sin^n x =1,$$ but it's just a mistake. My real question is $$\cos^n x -\sin^n x =1.$$

Comment: Please don't use the align environment in titles.

Comment: it changes nothing, see our answers

Comment: Are you interested in solving for $n$ or for $x$?  Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: surr for x ,  n just is integer parameter

Comment: The problem is easy for $n$ a positive integer. For negative integers the situation is different.

Comment: [Here's the question OP had already posted.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874442/solve-cosn-x-sinn-x-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, your equation is just:

$$\cos^n (-x) + \sin^n (-x) = 1$$

reducing the problem to one already solved.

Suppose that $n$ is even. We know that $\cos^n(x) \le 1$. If $\sin (x) \neq 0$, then $\sin^n(x) > 0$, hence $\cos^n (x) - \sin^n(x) < 1$, so there are no solutions. If $\sin (x) = 0$, then $x \in \pi \Bbb Z$, so $\cos^2(x) = 1$ and the equation holds.

Summary: for even $n$, the set of solutions is $\{\pi k, k \in \Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: yes if x is odd, the solution is clear but the other case please a small detail

Comment: @infox09 no the solution isn't clear for you

Comment: thank u ahmed  now it is clair